# PHP variable getting overwritten

Tags: php

Well, I am currently trying to write code which checks if a twitch stream is live or not. To do so I have created the array `$_SESSION['errors'];` On the second `.php` `$_SESSION['errors']` is either given 'live' or 'Not live', however whenever it goes back to the first `.php` page the `$_SESSION['errors']` will be overwritten at the point it was defined.

My question is, how, if possible would I get around this issue.

Code:

PHP in index.php:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['errors'] = '';
echo $_SESSION['errors'];
?>
```

PHP from streaminfo.php:

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST) === false) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    $streamer = $_POST['username'];
    $apiurl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" . $streamer;
    $apicontent = file_get_contents($apiurl);
    $streamerinfo = json_decode($apicontent);

            if ($streamerinfo->stream == '') {
                echo '<h2>' . 'Streamer is not live' . '</h2>';
                $_SESSION['errors'] = 'not live';
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
?>
```

I realise that I am overwriting the array when `index.php` is loaded, however I must define it and I dont know what to define it with.

Comment: Where is your `session_start();` ?

Comment: You *have* to define it? Why not check if it is defined and if it is not *then* you define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element is empty, and if so, you can define it.

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Do you have this in another file?
if (empty($_SESSION['errors'])) {
    $_SESSION['errors'] = '';
}
echo $_SESSION['errors'];
?>
```